# Docker disable restart on-failure

Tags: java, docker, docker-swarm

The following situation:

- I have a Spring Boot Application
- which runs in a Docker swarm
- but fails to start because it was not properly configured (a property is missing).
- It seems to me that the docker swarm always tries to restart the container, but always fails because of the missing property.
- The restart makes no sense because docker will never be able to start the application unless I fix the missing property.
- So currently the swarm ends in an endless loop.

Regarding this problem I already read:

- The docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/
- and several StackOverflow posts: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Docker+restart

My "setup":
The dockerfile:

```
ARG nexus_docker_registry=mynexus.com:10099
FROM ${nexus_docker_registry}/openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ADD myjar.jar myjar.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/myjar.jar" ]
```

my YML-file to create the docker service:

```
---
- hosts: docker_manager
  become: false

  vars:
    servicename: 'myservice'
    imageurl: "mynexus.com:10099/myjar:{{version}}"
    extraoptions:
      - "--with-registry-auth"
      - "--detach=true"
      - "--log-driver gelf"
      - "--log-opt 'gelf-address=udp://{{ groups['logstash'][0] }}:10001'"
      - "--hostname 'myhost.com'"
      - "--mount 'type=bind,source=/etc/localtime,destination=/etc/localtime:ro'"
      - "--mount 'type=volume,source=mykeys,destination=/mykeys'"
      - "--env 'spring.profiles.active=docker'"
      - "--publish 8000:6666"

  tasks:
    - name: Include vault
      include_vars: "myvault.yml"

    - name: "delete service '{{ servicename }}'"
      command: sudo docker service rm "{{ servicename }}"
      args:
        warn: false
      ignore_errors: true
      run_once: true

    - name: "create service {{ servicename }}"
      command: sudo docker service create {{ extraoptions | join( ' ' ) }} --name "{{ servicename }}" "{{ imageurl }}"
      args:
        warn: false
      run_once: true
```

What I want to achieve is:

- If the spring boot application is not able to start because of for example a `BeanCreationException` or something similar, then I don't want the docker service to restart endlessly.
- If I restart the swarm etc. the docker service should restart automatically.

In the docker documentation is written:

> If you manually stop a container, its restart policy is ignored until the Docker daemon restarts or the container is manually restarted. This is another attempt to prevent a restart loop.

So I guess that what I want to achieve is not possible with a restart policy.
Questions:

- but maybe I can write something in my `Dockerfile` that I achieve my goals?
- Or am I totally wrong here and misinterpret the documentation?

I am unfortunately not a docker expert and still learning to handle 'the swarm'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it does not seem possible what I wanted to achieve, I read the documentation again (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) and found the option `--restart-max-attempts` which will solve my problem with the endless loop.

Comment: Any idea if it can be implemented in a docker-compose for ```docker stack deploy```?

Comment: @RicarHincapie max_attempts config is available for docker-compose based on documentation but not 100% sure if this applies to `docker stack deploy`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 different [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details) in Docker:

- `no` - Do not automatically restart the container. (the default)
- `on-failure` - Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code.
- `always` - Always restart the container if it stops
- `unless-stopped` - Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.

There is no way for docker to "detect" a type of error from an application and restart or not depending on that.

One way to achieve this is to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) within your container and let that handle the restart depending of a list of exit codes that you define. But this means that your container will only restart when supervisord crashes, not when you application does and you'll have to change your code to return different exit codes on the errors that should be restarting and the ones that shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That means I was right with my assumption and docker does not provide this. Because of your answer I found another way to achieve what I want. I post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try and implement the creation of a `docker stack` based on a docker-compose file.

In this scenario, as the [compose v3 documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) indicates, you have full control over the service restart policy.

The next example won't allow restart:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    python:
        image: my_user/my_repo:my_container
        volumes:
            - /home/python:/home
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: none
```

You can adjust the `restart_policy` block with `condition: [none | on-failure | any]` and with `max_attempts: [your_int]`